# Geolocation module in IOS?

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation, titanium

In titanium studio we are using "Ti.geolocation" module for location based functions. So in the program we are checking that

```
if(Ti.geolocation) {

//code here

}
else{
 //code here
}
```

so that "geolocation" module is enabled for the app. My question: Is there any module available in Native IOS similar to Ti.geolocation so that i can check geolocation module is available or not, (other than "locationServicesEnabled" method because i dint mean this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to use `locationServicesEnabled` method:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    //code here        
}
else{
    //code here
}
```

Take a look at the [CLLocationManager's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).